# multi-tenancy Join or multiple Select queries postgres

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

I am implementing multi tenancy using single database and separating data for each tenant using a `tenant_id`. This id is passed in the jwt token as well. I have two tables right now `genre` and `books`. `genre` table has columns like
`tenant_id, genre_id, .....` and `books` table has columns `genre_id, book_id, book_name, ....`

So 1 genre can have multiple books associated with it and 1 tenant can have multiple genres associated with it.

Now every time a book is fetched or updated I want to make sure the right person is making these calls.

I know of two ways to do it.

**First way:**
Make two queries. First fetch the book, get the associated `genre_id` in the object. Then fetch that genre and compare the jwt `tenant_id` with the `tenant_id` inside this genre object.
Something like this

```
const book= await ReadBook(req.query.book_id);    // fetches my book from db
const genre = await ReadBook(book.genre_id);      // fetches the genre from db
if (genre.tenant_id === jwtToken.tenant_id) {..}  // compare if same or not
```

**Second way:**
Do this query in db

```
select b.*,  g.tenant_id as tenant_id 
from book_data b, genre_data g 
where b.book_id = '0eokdpz0l' and g.tenant_id = 'M1MzgzMDM' and b.genre_id = g.genre_id
```

Which method is more efficient?
If theres a more efficient method then these then please let me know too

Comment: Why did you decide to add both `mysql` and `postgresql` tags?

Comment: What I'm trying to do can be done by either of them (in exactly same way) so I put both

Comment: One tiny query = twice the network latency, two tiny queries = four times the network latency.

Comment: @SunAns It can also be done exactly the same way in **Oracle**, **SQLite** and **Ms SQL Server**, among others. If that's the logic, you could add most RDBMS tags, but I doubt this will be welcome. I think multi-tagging like that is typically perceived as either a mistake or an attempt to overpromote on additional, not necessarily adequate channels. If it's an early stage or small scale project that can still swap the db, it's worth mentioning in the question. Other than that, it's best to leave just the dialect you are actually using, plus plain `sql` due to how generic this is.

Comment: @Zegarek hey thanks for the info and yes you're right I should have just put sql. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to stick to ORM abstraction if possible, while minimising how much and how often data is transferred to/from db. Sequelize is able to construct an equivalent to that query for you, with the necessary joins and filters on the ids. Something among the lines of:

```js
Books.findAll({
  where: {book_id: '0eokdpz0l'},
  include: [{
    model: Genre,
    where: {tenant_id : jwtToken.tenant_id}
   }]
}).then(books => {
  /* ... */
});
```

Running multiple queries in sequence not only adds latency due to additional round trips to/from db (and possibly connection setup if you're not pooling or holding them open) but it's also moving more bytes of data around, needlessly. `tenant_id` mismatch on db would send back a shorter message with an empty result. Checking it on client side requires downloading data even when you'll have to discard it.